# How can i access my state variables in StyleSheet?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I calculate various margin's based on the images i'm displaying in my app, which range in different pixel widths each time images are selected, so my need us quite dynamic. Once i calculate the margin widths, i save them in state variables marginL and marginR.

However i can't seem to access these in StyleSheet, i just get an error message to say marginLeft is undefined.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1, 
    },
    gap: {
      flex: 0.5,
      marginLeft: this.state.marginL,
      marginRight: this.state.marginR
    }
})
```

How do i get access to my variables?

Comment: Is this code sample inside a stateful component? If so, could you include more of the component, especially how the (initial) state is set and when this object is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about dynamically changing in `StyleSheet` value. But when you calculate the margin widths you can override your style something like below

```
<View style={[styles.gap, {marginLeft: this.state.marginL, marginRight: this.state.marginR}]} />
```

Check complete example

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    marginL: 10,
    marginR: 20
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[ styles.gap, { marginLeft: this.state.marginL, marginRight: this.state.marginR }]} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  gap: {
    flex: 0.5,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
});
```

This not be the optimal solution but hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Hi, this is the only solution i've found that works so far (i am currently using it), but it doesn't feel as concise as having the values in the StyleSheet itself. It's like variables are spread in 2 areas (in Render and in StyleSheet). Thanks

Comment: @chai86 as I mention, this may not be the optimal solution